# Construct a sequence subsequential limits of which form a range $[a, b]\subset \Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to:

> construct a sequence subsequential limits of which form a range $[a, b]\subset \Bbb R$

Not sure how to express myself correctly but I will try.

I was thinking of a range from $a$ to $b$. If i could split that range infinitely many times and always choose either left or right part, then I could use that "path" as a subsequence. From that i should be able to find infinitely many subsequences which with some reordering will form a sequence containing any number in the range $[a, b]$ as its subsequential limit.

I've been playing around with this idea in desmos, [here is a basic sketch of the idea](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cz67qdaklc).

Could someone help me construct such a sequence? Is my approach even valid? If so then how could i finish it?

Comment: enumerate rationals in $[a,b]$

Comment: I can't see anything but empty space in desmos.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I've fixed the link, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I click on your link, I just get the Desmos home page.

On the other hand, you can take the sequence:$$a,b,a,\frac12a+\frac12b,b,a,\frac23a+\frac13b,\frac13a+\frac23b,b,a,\frac34a+\frac14b,\ldots$$

Comment: That's the one! I just could't wrap my mind around it, thank you!

Comment: I just realized that my answer is essentially the same as you. I should have read carefully first.

Answer (score 2):

If $[a,b]=[0,1]$ then you can take the sequence
$$
\frac 11, \frac 12, \frac 22, \frac 13, \frac 23, \frac 33, \frac 14, \frac 24, \frac 34, \frac 44, \dots
$$
It shouldn't be hard to see that any point in $[0,1]$ can be approximated arbitrarily well.

For general $[a,b]$ just linearly transform the above.

Answer (score 2):

Its famous that {$\sin (n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is dense in $[-1,+1]$. So, shift to the interval of interest:
$$ \{a+ (b-a) \sin n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \ .$$